# Remote desktop connection black screen on ICS, but ok when on WiFi

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, internet-connection, remote, ics

Working:
One computer is connected to the router by cable (remote desktop host) and the other one through WiFi(client computer). In this configuration all works fine.

Not working:
Now to get better internet in my client computer I connected an ethernet cable from host to share internet connection. Wifi is now disabled. The internet works, but with this configuration remote connection doesn't work. I managed to make it working by disabling visual compositions, wallpaper and all the effects in RDP but this isn't perfect. This workaround seemed to solve the problem but then I opened a full screen image and that crashed my RDP.
So it looks like that things are crashing when transferring large pictures(you can see that the picture was sent in 30% and then all freezes).

Comment: Have you portforwarded your computer in your router?

Answer (score 1):

I run Windows 7 remote desktop to another Windows 7 desktop. I often get a black screen and found that the following works for me. After launching Remote Desktop, click on Show Options, and then click on the Experience tab. I change the "Persistent bitmap caching" checkbox (from checked to unchecked or the other way) and then login again. The works for me and sure beats an hour round trip to remote the remote host.